# How to use a variable in Javascript as string and variable?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, local-storage, whitespace

Is there a way to take a variable and use it as an input for the localStorage, then edit it to remove the spaces? What I have been trying to do is set a variable to the value of the local storage, then edit it. The problem is that Javascript won't allow me to use a string variable for this but I can't edit a normal variable. Here is my code:

```html
    var retrieveLocal = localStorage.getItem('transferData');
retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.replaceAll(\s+ , '');
  retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.toLowerCase();
  console.log(retrieveLocal);
```

The error I'm getting is SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at index.html:11:5)

Comment: Your description makes it very unclear as to what exactly is happening. Please post the code you tried, and what specific issues you had with it, including the actual text of any errors.

Comment: Show a [mcve] of the code representing the problem, and describe your problem. You haven't actually said what your problem is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your regular expression syntax is wrong. You either need to do `retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.replaceAll(/\s+/, '')` or `retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.replaceAll(new RegExp('\s+') , '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
localStorage.setItem('transferData', "This is the simple string");
var retrieveLocal = localStorage.getItem('transferData');
console.log('retrieveLocal', retrieveLocal);
const regex = / /g;
retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.replaceAll(regex, '');
retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.toLowerCase();
console.log(retrieveLocal);
```

```js
localStorage.setItem('transferData', "This is the simple string");
var retrieveLocal = localStorage.getItem('transferData');
console.log('retrieveLocal', retrieveLocal);
const regex = / /g;
retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.replaceAll(regex, '');
retrieveLocal = retrieveLocal.toLowerCase();
console.log(retrieveLocal);
```